# Unable to click buttons using Selenium with Python (JavaScript did not work either)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

https://www.fire.ca.gov/incidents/2018/[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Z5K.png**strong text**

The idea was trying to pull all the acres burnt on total of 31 pages. Tried with regular click and JS click but both failed. No error was reported it was just the buttons that was not functional --- It never left page 1 so basically I got the same numbers 31 times.

Any useful advice will be much appreciated cuz I literally spent a whole day trying to click several god damn buttons.

```
for i in range(31):
    records = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('responsive-table-row')
    for n in range(1,11):
        record_single = records[n].find_elements_by_class_name('responsive-table-cell')
        try:
            acres = record_single[3].find_element_by_tag_name('span').text  
        except:
            acres = 'N/A'
    
        ws.append([acres])

    buttons = driver.find_element_by_class_name('pagination-navigation')
    button_parent = buttons.find_element_by_tag_name('ul')
    button_list = button_parent.find_elements_by_tag_name('li') 
    if i <30:
        #button_list[i+1].click
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()',button_list[i+1])
        time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button_list contains the li's.

Your script is attempting the click the list items (li) structure , not the anchor within it (a).
If you look at the source, the li doesn't contain anything. The anchor contains  javascript href and should fire the event to navigate the page.

In your solution, in your loop at the end, you'll want to do something like:

```
Button_list[i+1].find_element_by_tag_name('a').click
```

Alternatively, you can combine all those finds into 1 xpath.  Open chromedevtools, press control+f and enter this:
*[edit] updated xpath*

```
//*[@class='pagination-navigation']/ul/li
```

That will create a list of all the li's.

*[edit] Added this bit*

Additionally, you can add the `/a` to the end and directly create a a list of buttons (still using find element**s**):

```
//*[@class='pagination-navigation']/ul/li/a
```

In my dev tools, this matches 31 elements.

That returns multiple matches and you can use that to populate your button_list. There's lots of resources out there to help you learn how to use xpath - just give it a Google :-)

Comment: Find element and click still didn't work but when combined with javascript it actually worked! A million thanks! Btw I entered that xpath as suggested but there was no match. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: Just waiting to be at me desk on Monday and I'll sort it. :-) In the interim, have look here for a tutorial on Web locators : https://testautomationu.applitools.com/web-element-locator-strategies/

Comment: Appreciate it :-)

Comment: i put it as@id, but it's @class! - i'll update the answer.....

Comment: That was really helpful for a beginner! Genuine thanks :-)